# How to return Int from an if-else block instead of anyVal in scala?

Tags: scala, if-statement, return-value

I am a newbie in Scala. I was trying to use a if-else block in scala to try and return a "Int".

My code looks something likie this:

```
val blockNumber = {
    if(x.getName equals ("NATIVE")) 0
    else {
       if(x.getName equals ("DATIVE")) 1
    }
}
```

I use this value `blockNumber` in the method `setBlockNumber()` and this where the problem occurs:

```
 new setBlockNumber(Option(blockNumber))
```

But everytime I try to do this the method gives an error saying :

```
type mismatch; found : AnyVal required: Int
```

Can somebody please point out my mistake and how can I rectiy it? Thankyou for your time in advance.

Comment: What value do you want if `x.getName` is neither `"NATIVE"` nor `"DATIVE"`?

Comment: It should nothing then. I mean the val should be empty

Comment: What is "empty" mean in regards to `blockNumber`? What is an empty number?

Comment: **Every branch** must return an `Int` in order to get an `Int` back. Your last `if` doesn't return anything so compiler gives you least upper bound, `AnyVal`.

Comment: @insan-e My last if tries to return a 1. Isn't that the right way?

Comment: @Goldengirl but it doesn't have the `else` part!? The default value or whatever.. You must return something.

Comment: val x = if(something) 1 else 0 // x will always be of type Int - 

val x = if(something) 1 // x can be of type Int, but in other cases it isn't clear what type it should have. So type inferred is AnyVal

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After reading the comments, I believe what you want is to store an `Option[Int]` in `blockNumber`:

```
val blockNumber = if (x.getName == "NATIVE") {
    Some(0)
} else if (x.getName == "DATIVE") {
    Some(1)
} else {
    None
}

new setBlockNumber(blockNumber)
```

I would also rewrite this using `match`:

```
val blockNumber = x.getName match {
    case "NATIVE" => Some(0)
    case "DATIVE" => Some(1)
    case _ => None
}
new setBlockNumber(blockNumber)
```

Comment: Yes, or just put the **map**pings in a `Map` and call `get x.getName`... xD (if equals is the only condition of course)

Comment: It's an interesting idea. But it could be quite "misunderstandable". I think the match solution is quite fitting.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to clearify why you get AnyVal instead of Int. I don't want to be offensive, but it seems like you are also new to programming...?

Under the assumption that your code would do what you want, your second If is not really senseful. One would write:

```
val blockNumber = {
        if(x.getName equals ("NATIVE")) 0
        else if(x.getName equals ("DATIVE")) 1
    }
```

Which is still AnyVal. Because in the case if either "NATIVE" or "DATIVE" won't match the compiler doesn't know what value you will deliver and therefore it's Unit. The common supertype of Unit and Int is AnyVal.

So your code with missing Paths:

```
val blockNumber = {
    if(x.getName equals ("NATIVE")) 0
    else {
       if(x.getName equals ("DATIVE")) 1
       else Unit
    }
}
```

So you have basically 2 If-Statements nested in each other. The first one asks if the value of x.getName is "NATIVE" and the other one is an general else path which is normally for handling the default or all other cases. But you put another if in there without an else path which would resolve in Unit. As already stated the common supertype of Int and Unit is AnyVal.

Under the assumption you have only 2 cases "NATIVE" and "DATIVE" you could write:

```
val blockNumber = if(x.getNmae equal ("NATIVE")) 0
else 1
```

Otherwise the match-case approach of @Dogbert is the way to go. If there is a possibility that none of the cases could happen you should use Option as @Dogbert did. Otherwise if at least one of your cases will match you may use Int without Option.

Kind regards, hope it helps!